# CSS - transform with same scale ratio did not work for videos with same aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api, aspect-ratio

I use css properties:

```
transform:scale(1.35);
```

to remove the black bars on YouTube video. It works well on almost of videos, but there are some exceptions. I know this is caused by aspect ratio. I have same aspect ratio 16:9 for these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vMH8lITTCE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALZHF5UqnU4

But why cannot I set the same scale for them? This scale ratio only works well for second one.

P/S:
Get aspect ratio for above video on YouTube by using YT API:

```
var player = document.getElementById('movie_player');
player.getVideoAspectRatio();//==> 1.7777 for both.
```

Set transform is scale for video:
Using inspect element to point to video tag, and add following css for video tag:

```
transform:scale(1.35);
```

What is the best way to remove black bars in this case? I cannot set this value so high, because a part of video will be lost. The most important thing I want to know, why this value (1.35) cannot work well for the first one. I test many cases, it works well for all videos with aspect ratios (16:9, 21:9).

Answer (score 0):

One of the videos must have black bars encoded into it. It would be very hard to analyse the video and detect this, so you either have to accept it, choose a different version of the video without bars, or enter the video's 'real' aspect ratio by hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src*='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src*='//www.youtube.com'], object, embed"),
$fluidEl = $("figure");
$allVideos.each(function() {    
  $(this)
    // jQuery .data does not work on object/embed elements
    .attr('data-aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');   
}); 

$(window).resize(function() {      
  $allVideos.each(function() {    
    var $el = $(this);
    var newWidth = $el.parents('figure').width();
    $el
        .width(newWidth)
        .height(newWidth * $el.attr('data-aspectRatio'));     
  });   
}).resize();
```

Back there [this repository](https://github.com/chriscoyier/Fluid-Width-Video) helped me a lot with that kind of problem

Comment: Did you test for above videos ?